# SSRS/MDX - A table with dataset pulled from a cube needs a column whose data is in sql db

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

I have a dataset that was build using MDX (analysis cube). I have a table with few columns. Now, I need to add one more column with specific data that is available in sql db and not cube. I know it is not possible to do that. What can I do to work around this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you've using 2008R2, so you can use the LOOKUP or LOOKUPSET functions to match items from one datasource to another:

http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/04/07/sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services-look-up-part-iii/

It was released two years ago, so hopefully you're up to date?

Comment: Thanks for this. I was looking at this after I posted this question. Will check it out soon. This "might" work for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can, for each rows in your table, define a subreport that pulls the data from sql server based upon the mdx dataset. Note that the query to sql server will be made as many times as the number of records in your mdx dataset.

Comment: I will have quite a few records on one page (at least 15-20). I need to add a column to the existing table...

Comment: @Meff answer is actually better for your case. LOOKUP is the function to use when you want to fetch data from a dataset while displaying another one.